# clear console keyboard shortcut for rubymine 6

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, rubymine

I used to be able to map a key for this back in rubymine 4.5+.. but if i go to `preferences -> keymap` I can't find an action that identifies it.. although it has an icon and it appears in the context menu as well..

I tried searching for `clear` and `clear all` but got nothing on the rubymine preferences search.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File -> Settings -> Keymap` search `Clear all` and add shortcut, some like: <kbd>⎇</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

[image]

Comment: which version of ruby mine are you using?

Comment: @abbood I use IntelliJ IDEA 13, but in the RubyMine have this [feature](http://goo.gl/P31kxo) is also.

Comment: @abbood See also a similar [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11444277/2650174).

Comment: oh just so that i don't feel like i'm seeing things.. this happened to me second time.. i think u gotta do it a couple of times until you finally see the clear all lol